# Does "strict library" mean a library that is strict about its rules and law and order?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does "strict library" mean a library that is strict about its rules and law and order? Can "strict" be used with regard to places or organizations?

The context:

> A tinkling bell rang somewhere in the depths of the shop as they stepped
>   inside. It was a tiny place, empty except for a single, spindly chair
>   that Hagrid sat on to wait. Harry felt strangely as though he had
>   entered a very **strict library**; he swallowed a lot of new questions that
>   had just occurred to him and looked instead at the thousands of narrow
>   boxes piled neatly right up to the ceiling. For some reason, the back of
>   his neck prickled. The very dust and silence in here seemed to tingle
>   with some secret magic.

Comment: A strict library is one where silence is maintained, and/or where there are rigid processes in place for accessing and handling library materials.

Answer (score 2):

Your explanation is exactly right. If a library is strict, typically that means that people must be quiet, that certain sections might be off limits, and that rules are vigilantly enforced.

"Strict" can be applied to many places and institutions, such as churches, schools, classrooms, workplaces, etc.  In every case, this means that, at these places, rules are strictly enforced.

Comment: Thanks - I missed see the second part of the question :)